# What are some resources on the roots of critical/cultural theory?

Tags: reference-request, critical-theory

Who was the first philosopher to write seriously on the topic of movies, cinema, video games and other modern artifacts of popular culture?

Is there a good reference covering the birth of this branch of philosophy (critical theory?)

Comment: We still need a clearer idea of what you mean by pop philosophy. Also, this is really pretty broad.

Comment: @Canyon for me is that philosophy find the philosophy behind the structure of novels and books like: Minority Report, Do Androids dream electric sheep, video games (in general) etc

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio The difficulty in answering this is that people have always related philosophy to the popular culture of their times --Plato and Aristotle certainly did.  However, you might enjoy my own blog, http://popculturephilosopher.com

Comment: tnx @ChrisSunami but I think that someone started to apply, for ex. the idea of free will or predestination, looking at Hollywood

Comment: Maybe you want to ask "who was the first philosopher to write seriously on the topic of movies and the cinema?"  or something similar.

Comment: @ChrisSunami that could be a good start. With this I can response to: when, and where it born

Comment: In regards to the first question you were asking, [there's an entire stack exchanged devoted to literature](http://literature.stackexchange.com/) and you will probably be better off getting an answer there. What you are asking about in regards to pop philosophy, to me, sounds like you're just asking about literary, art, film, etc. criticism which is in the domain of critical studies. There is a good starting point for understanding literary theory [here](http://www.iep.utm.edu/literary/). Even though criticism isn't called philosophy (usually), this is the topic you're looking for.

Comment: The term "pop philosophy" has a bad connotation, it usually means someone boiling complex philosophical ideas down to terms that are acceptable in popular culture and inso doing they underrepresent  and misinterpret ideas. Using pop philosophy articles as sources in an academic paper would be a horrible idea. I am very confident that what you are actually looking for is literary criticism of the books you're talking about. Citing a pop philosophy article or book in a paper would be like citing a dailymail article for a physics paper, that is a horrible idea.

Comment: There's a whole series of books "Batman and Philosophy", "Southpark and Philosophy", "Harry Potter and Philosophy",...that might help.  Critical Theory (Adorno, Horkheimer, more recently Zizek,...) examines pop culture from a philosophical point of view,...this question is way too broad to provide objective answers. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @Not_Here tnx for the suggestions but the question is still there. I mean as an introduction of a paper how can I focus the pop philosophy or, at least, where can I find the story about it?

Comment: @AlexanderSKing tnx, I bought "Batman and Philosophy" but it can not answer to my question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_theory#History is going to answer the question that you have written down right now. This question is not about popular philosophy though, that term doesn't mean what you think it means if this is a related question to your other question. Russell's book [history of western philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_History_of_Western_Philosophy) is a work of popular philosophy, it has nothing to do with a philosophical study of popular culture. What you are looking for is [critical theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_theory).

Comment: What usually happens is that creators of movies/videogames adopt some philosophy and "implement" it artistically. A well-known example is Baudrillard's  Simulacra and Simulation as inspiration for The Matrix, although [Baudrillard himself](https://www.quora.com/What-relationship-if-any-exists-between-The-Matrix-and-Jean-Baudrillards-Simulacra-and-Simulation) apparently criticized the movie. [Zizek](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2012/09/10/beyond-the-matrix) also wrote about it.

Comment: I think that the substance of this question is "*when (and through whom) has 'philosophy' started to consider the transformations in arts due to the invention of its mechanical reproductibility?*" Put like this, the question answers itself: https://www.marxists.org/reference/subject/philosophy/works/ge/benjamin.htm - or, as @Not_Here puts it, critical theory.

Comment: After the rewording of the question: I'm pretty sure you are looking for Adorno and Horkheimer's [Culture Industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_industry) and Adorno's subsequent writing on the topic, and Guy Debord's [la Société du Spectacle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Society_of_the_Spectacle)

Comment: [Critical Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/critical-theory/) is a well known phil movement. See also [Max Horkheimer](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/horkheimer/), [Theodor W. Adorno](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/adorno/) and [Frankfurt School](http://www.iep.utm.edu/frankfur/).

Comment: @ChrisSunami that's definitely a helpful edit, although it's pretty much a total reformulation... --I wonder if the headline could be sharpened a bit further? It could be framed a little more explicitly as a resource-request to reflect the content a little more closely ("What are some resources on the roots of critical/cultural theory?") --Also curious what OP makes of this [although I now see he has confirmed this is pretty close to what he's after]

Comment: @JosephWeissman I based the edits on the comments, including from the OP.  Can we get it reopened? It seems like there's no dearth of good answers judging from the comments section.

Comment: On movies, see [Gregory Currie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_Currie): e.g. [Image and Mind: Film, Philosophy and Cognitive Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=oDjrYDPO_20C&printsec=frontcover), [Stephen Mulhall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Mulhall) with [On Film](https://books.google.it/books?id=BcI0CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) and mainly: [Stanley Cavell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Cavell) with [The World Viewed](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ro23ozNGdzQC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Also [Gilles Deleuze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilles_Deleuze), [On Cinema](https://books.google.it/books?id=ym-OM6y2ULgC), I and II.

Comment: See also [David Rodowick's books](https://www.google.it/search?q=david+rodowick&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjppJfA6_TSAhUJLhoKHaabAdkQ_AUIDSgG&biw=1517&bih=708).

Comment: Andre Bazin was a very important "early" French writer on film. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/André_Bazin

Answer (score 1):

*This answer mainly collects suggestions given in the comments section:*

**Wiki**

- [Popular Culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popular_culture)
- [Film theory - History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_theory#History)

**Articles:**

- [The Pop Culture Manifesto](https://philosophynow.org/issues/64/The_Pop_Culture_Manifesto)
- [Fancy Taking Pop](https://www.psychologytoday.com/files/attachments/55564/fancy-taking-pop.pdf)
- [Pop Culture and Philosophy Books](https://philosophynow.org/issues/64/Pop_Culture_and_Philosophy_Books)

**Books:**

- [*Philosophy and the Interpretation of Pop Culture*](http://a.co/cb2ITfL)
- [*Seinfeld and Philosophy: A Book about Everything and Nothing*](http://a.co/2mKrFBR)

Comment: I read the Philosophy Now manifesto. In the 3rd section, not only does he fail to mention critical theory, but he dismisses the idea of a "philosophy of pop culture" all together, which is strange. Like someone talking about economics but not mentioning Marx and saying that a philosophy of economics is useless.

Comment: In the Frankfurt School, you will see a mix of Marx and Freud. Russell Jacoby's book "Social Amnesia" is good.  Erich Fromm's book "Beyond the Chains of Illusion: My Encounter with Marx and Freud" is interesting.  It is often forgotten that Fromm was an early member of the Frankfurt School. Also, we should remember those outside the School:  Paul Nazin, French, "The Watchdogs". I also mentioned Andre Bazin on film, very important.

Answer (score 1):

Critical theory, focused among other things on popular culture, dates I should say from the Frankfurt School founded in 1923 at the Institut fur Sozialforschung. There are no abrupt beginnings in the history of social theory; prefigurations of the work of the Frankfurt School are evident in Georg Simmel or even earlier in (how can we avoid the name ?) Marx.

Early members of the Frankfurt School included Carl Grunberg, Max Horkheimer. Friedrich Pollock, Leo Lowenthal, Theodor Adorno, Herbert Marcuse, and Erich Fromm formed an inner circle around Horkheimer, who became Director in 1930. It was in the 1930s and 40s that the School started to pay serious, systematic attention to the Nazi penetration of German society, to aesthetics, and to popular culture.

The School's influence greatly expanded when under Nazi hostility it relocated to Holland in 1931 and, of crucial importance, when in 1934 it re-established itself as the 'Institute of Social Research' at Columbia University in New York. 
The transatlantic transfer transformed the School into a formidably influential intellectual force.

A useful source is Martin Jay, The Dialectical Imagination. Boston: Little, Brown and Company, 1973.

Since there was so much collaborative work in the School, it is perhaps invidious to name the first philosopher who undertook the type of social analysis you are interested in. But Horkheimer's inaugural lecture as Director, 'The Present Situation of Social Philosophy and the Tasks of an Institute for Social Research', puts popular culture clearly in its sights. See Max Horkheimer, 'Between Philosophy and Social Science: Selected Early Writings',
tr. Frederick Hunter, Matthew S. Kramer, John Torpey, Cambridge: MIT Press, 1993.